# Groovy: remove and object from a list within itself?

Tags: arrays, list, groovy

I'm trying to remove objects from a list when it finds that particular objects privacy
is private to the current user

```
     books.eachWithIndex{ obj, i ->

        if((obj.book.private).equals(true)){

          def status = bookService.getBookStatus(obj.book)

          if(!status){
               books.remove(i)
          }
        }
     }
```

error thrown as it tries to remove the object

ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - null
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Q: is there any way to remove an object from a list within itself
or would you have to separately store the index values and remove objects from outside the each loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A more functional approach may help:

```
def publicBooks = books.findAll { obj ->
    !obj.book.isPrivate() || bookService.getBookStatus(obj.book) 
}
```

Note that findAll() returns a *new* collection rather than modifying the existing one.

Answer (score 2):

There is an iterator that has a .remove() method, but I don't know if that functionality has been translated into groovyesque.  It doesn't work with Java's enhanced for either.

Try iterating over it manually (with an iterator, normal old-school Java-style for loop) and use the iterator.remove()... Unless Groovy has provided you with access to the iterator, it's the only way to do it while you are iterating.

Answer (score 0):

The [hibernate filters plugin](http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2010/07/13/grails-hibernate-filter-plugin-a-life-saver/) was created for exactly this kind of scenario.  I've used it on our current project to do this kind of filtering.